# How to add a MultiIndex after loading csv data into a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to add additional index rows to an existing pandas dataframe after loading csv data into it.

So let's say I load my data like this:

```
columns = ['Relative_Pressure','Volume_STP']
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(contents), skiprows=4, delim_whitespace=True,index_col=False,header=None)
df.columns = columns
```

where `contents` is a string in csv format. The resulting DataFrame might look something like this:

[image: Imported csv data]

For clarity reasons I would now like to add additional index rows to the DataFrame as shown [here](https://notes.mikejarrett.ca/storing-metadata-in-pandas-dataframes/):

[image: MulitIndex dataframe]

However in the link these multiple index rows are generated right when the DataFrame is created. I would like to add e.g. rows for `unit` or `descr` to the columns.

How could I do this?

Comment: The solution provided at your link looks ingenious, and a bit too so. Using multi-index for metadata storage has non-trivial impacts on performance and sub-optimal maintainability for future updates. The easiest solution is to provide a README for the data. A better solution is to create a subclass, but only add a `metadata` property with print_metadata to print it. You can optionally override `__str__` and `__unicode__` to print metadata first, and then the `super().__str__` and `super().__unicode__`. But if you are distributing a library with data, it's easier to give them a text README.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a `MultiIndex` on the columns by specifically creating the index and then assigning it to the columns separately from reading in the data.

I'll use the example from the [link you provided](https://notes.mikejarrett.ca/storing-metadata-in-pandas-dataframes/). The first method is to create the MultiIndex when you make the dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({('A',1,'desc A'):[1,2,3],('B',2,'desc B'):[4,5,6]})
df.columns.names=['NAME','LENGTH','DESCRIPTION']
df

NAME             A      B
LENGTH           1      2
DESCRIPTION desc A desc B
0                1      4
1                2      5
2                3      6
```

As stated, this is *not* what you are after. Instead, you can make the dataframe (from your file for example) and then make the `MultiIndex` from a set of lists and then assign it to the columns:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'desc A':[1,2,3], 'desc B':[4,5,6]})

# Output
   desc A  desc B
0       1       4
1       2       5
2       3       6

# Create a multiindex from lists
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays((['A', 'B'],  [1, 2], ['desc A', 'desc B']))

# Assign to the columns
df.columns = index


# Output
       A      B
       1      2
  desc A desc B
0      1      4
1      2      5
2      3      6


# Name the columns
df.columns.names = ['NAME','LENGTH','DESCRIPTION']

# Output
NAME             A      B
LENGTH           1      2
DESCRIPTION desc A desc B
0                1      4
1                2      5
2                3      6
```

There are other ways to construct a `MultiIndex`, for example, `from_tuples` and `from_product`. You can read more about [Multi Indexes in the documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/advanced.html).